# why is this simplest angular test is not working?

Tags: angular

Here is my component. I have list of movie named `movies`. I want to test if the count of movies is correct or not using angular test.

```
import {AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, EventEmitter, Injector, Input, OnInit, Output, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Select, Store} from '@ngxs/store';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

export interface News {
  heading:string,
  text:string
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
      <p>hello</p>
    <h1>Welcome to angular-test!</h1>
    <div class="movie" *ngFor="let movie of movies">{{movie.title}}</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent{

  title="angular-test";
  movies = [
    { title: 'Interstellar' },
    { title: 'The big Lebowski' },
    { title: 'Fences' }
  ]
}
```

**Here is my test:**

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {By} from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('render', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

  }));

  it('should show all the movies', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const movieElement = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.movie'));
    console.log(movieElement)//prints: []
    expect(movieElement.length).toEqual(3);
  });
});
```

However when i run my test using `ng test`, I get:

```
Chrome 72.0.3626 (Windows 10.0.0) render should show all the movies FAILED
        Expected 0 to equal 3.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/src/app/app.component.spec.ts?:21:33)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:391:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:289:1)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:390:1)
Chrome 72.0.3626 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.355 secs / 0.339 secs)
```

Can someone pls advice?

Note: When i run `ng s` I can see the `movies` array rendered correctly

Comment: You need to call fixture.detectChanges() after you've created the component. https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-dom-testing

Comment: Hey thanks! That worked. I am following this [snippet](https://gist.github.com/FunnyGhost/fb42c3925d1fcd9f3c7bb54b17f9b6e3#file-favorite-movies-component-spec-ts) from an article. Really bad article.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happening because the component detection not applied in your test suite. To solve your problem you need to call  `fixture.detectChanges();` in `beforeEach`.

**Solution**

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {By} from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('render', () => {

  let component: AppComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  })


 it('should show all the movies', () => {
   const movieElement = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.movie'));
   console.log(movieElement)//prints: []
   expect(movieElement.length).toEqual(3);
 });
});
```

> [**Offcial Documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-dom-testing)

Hope this will help!